# How to implement fuzz testing for a GCC C++ project

Tags: fuzz-testing, c++

I want to implement continuous integrated fuzz testing for my c++ project, but I have to use GCC due to a dependency.
I know there is fuzz testing for LLVM (libFuzzer). Is there something similar for GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [AFL++](https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus) (American Fuzzy Lop plus plus) has a [gcc_plugin](https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus/blob/stable/instrumentation/README.gcc_plugin.md)

> AFL++ is a superior fork to [Google's AFL](https://github.com/google/AFL) - more speed, more and better
> mutations, more and better instrumentation, custom module support,
> etc.

I think you can use AFL++ with [OSS-Fuzz](https://github.com/google/oss-fuzz) or [ClusterFuzz](https://github.com/google/clusterfuzz) to implement continuous integration.

**note**: I have no experience fuzz-testing, but I am pretty good with web-searches.

Comment: Thanks for your Google work!

Comment: I will try to get this up and running 